# Geometry question about the side lengths of a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

[image: Diagram]

For this question, since it doesn't specify the type of trapezoid, I assumed the trapezoid was isosceles and let $AD=2$, $BC=4$, and $AB=10$ (am I even allowed to do this?). After that, I found the area of the trapezoid to be $3\sqrt{99}$ and thus the areas of the two regions formed by $MN$. However, I don't know where to go from here, or even if my method works.

Comment: For calculating the value of $1 + x + y^2$, you can make any assumption that you want. However, if it was a proof-based olympiad problem (which you are likely working up towards), then you cannot add additional assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $K$ be the area of the trapezoid and partition it into four parts, *I*, *II*, *III*, and *IV*. Given the ratios AM:MB = 3:2 and AD:BC = 1:2, we express the areas below as,

$$K = \frac32ah$$
$$III = \frac12\cdot 2a\cdot \frac25h = \frac4{15}K,\>\>\>\>\>IV = \frac12 \cdot a\cdot \frac35h =\frac15K,$$

$$I+II = K - (III + IV) = \frac8{15}K$$
$$I = \frac y{x+y}\cdot \frac8{15}K,\>\>\>\>\>
II = \frac x{x+y}\cdot \frac8{15}K$$

Substitute above areas into the ratio,

$$\frac{I+IV}{II+III} = \frac13=\frac{\frac y{x+y}\cdot \frac8{15} + \frac1{5} }
{ \frac x{x+y}\cdot \frac8{15} + \frac4{15} }$$

which yields $x:y=29:3$. Thus,

$$1+x+y^2 = 1+ 29 + 3^2 = 39$$